# How to look for a photography "fixer" in Brazil?

Tags: brazil, photography

I'm a non-professional photographer looking to visit Rio and possibly Sao Paulo, I'm interested in shooting the life in the favellas but understand that it is a rather risky proposition in terms of chances of getting robbed or worse.

How should I go about arranging a "fixer" who will accompany me, communicate with the locals, help me navigate situations etc. while avoiding the more shady hustlers and "poverty porn" tour operators. ?

Is hiring an off-duty plain clothes police officer a viable option ?

Answer (score 8):

Hiring a police officer to show you around a Rio favela sounds like a terrible idea to me. The police is currently not viewed benignly by most residents of Rio's favelas. [Context](https://www.huffpostbrasil.com/entry/brazil-police-violence-madonna-rio_us_59f9dc68e4b0d1cf6e91f1ef).

If you are not a journalist yourself, and/or have no contacts you could reach out to, you could try starting [here](https://paydesk.co/journalists/in/brazil), [here](http://www.rioonwatch.org) or [here](https://www.facebook.com/search/str/network+for+foreigners+in+brazil/keywords_groups).

That said, starting with a favela tour would probably not be a bad idea. I hear good things about the Santa Marta tour (which might be [this one](https://www.yelp.com/biz/favela-santa-marta-tour-rio-de-janeiro?adjust_creative=dWJMtmYxpd5N5yoyzSuhtA&utm_campaign=yelp_api&utm_medium=api_v2_search&utm_source=dWJMtmYxpd5N5yoyzSuhtA)) and [this one](http://favelatour.com.br) seems to be well-respected, too.

Perhaps it doesn't need to be said, but "shooting the life in the favellas" can quickly become "poverty porn".